# How to save selected DropDownList value in ASP.NET MVC model for POST?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a property inside my model, like this:

```
 public IList<SelectListItem> AllCards { get; set; }
```

Property is being filled with `SelectListItem`'s by controller with data from database.

Also, in my View is `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.AllCards,Model.AllCards,"--Select--")`.
Problem occures during POSTing of a view. That is, onSubmit my `Model.AllCards` is empty, although there is a value selected inside dropdownlist.
I tried adding a new property to the model like this:

```
public SelectListItem SelectedCard
```

and then changing the view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.AllCards,Model.SelectedCard,"--Select--")
```

but it gives me an error saying conversion not possible, sth like that.

What should I do to catch my dropdownlist value so that it can be inside model once POST version of a view is called?
Thank you

P.S. I know there are ten similar questions but none of them help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I would have done it.

Your view model could look like this and will have a list of cards:

```
public class CardViewModel
{
     public int CardId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

I do not know what properties your card has but let me invent my own:

```
public class Card
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your view will accept this view model:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Cards.CardViewModel
```

Your HTML markup for the cards drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.CardId,
     new SelectList(Model.Cards, "Id", "Name", Model.CardId),
     "-- Select --",
     new { id = "Cards" }
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CardId)
```

Your action method when the view loads for the first time:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
     CardViewModel viewModel = new CardViewModel
     {
          Cards = cardService.FindAll()
     }

     return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(CardViewModel viewModel)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View(viewModel);
     }

     // Do what ever you need to do. The selected card's id will now be populated

     return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

Regarding your JavaScript question I woudld advise that you start a new question, but I will give an outline on what you can look out for.  Separate your JavaScript and HTML by adding the on change event using `jQuery` (use whatever you want to).  For example:

```
<script>

     $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Cards").change(function () {
               alert('cards value has changed');
          });
     });

</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add another property to your model of the same type as the `value` parameter for your `SelectListItems`.  For example, if it's an `int`, do this:

```
public int SelectedCard { get; set; }
```

Then, change your `DropDownListFor` like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCard, new SelectList(Model.AllCards), "--Select--")
```

I'm not sure why you're using an `IList<SelectListItem>` instead of simply using a `SelectList`.  If you do the latter, then you don't need the `new SelectList` constructor call in the above.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using DropDownListFor correctly:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Model.SelectedCard, Model.AllCards,"--Select--")
```

In your model:

```
   public SelectList AllCards {get; set;}
   public int SelectedCard {get; set;}
```

Comment: I think above should be m.SelectedCard not m.Model.SelectedCard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, AJ helped me a great deal to come up with this, so thanks:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChosenCard, Model.AllCreditCards, "--Select--", new { onchange = "GetOtherItem()" } )
```

where `ChosenCard` is of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and `AllCreditCards` is `IList<SelectListItem>`.

So, that is the correct way.