# get index combobox after selectedindexchanged mvc c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, combobox, selectedindex

In ASP.NET, I'm not ablet to get the updated value of the SelectedItem from the ComboBox. I've tried various ways but still could not get the value of the index of the combobox. I hope you can help me to fix my problem.
[image]

I have a combobox with few items and the default setting selectedindex is 0 (first item). After submitting I go to another form. The issue is, that when submitting the form, the default value is saved as opposed to what I have selected from the list.
this is combobox view :

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBoxFor(m => m.NMUNIT, settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "UNIT_ID_CB";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "App", Action = "cbPartialCategories" };
    settings.Properties.ValueField = "KDUNIT";
    settings.Properties.TextField = "NMUNIT";
    settings.SelectedIndex = 18;
}).BindList((new eFaktur_Model.Lov.lovCategories().ListKategori() )).GetHtml()
```

this is partial view to load combobox :

```
groupItem.Items.Add(item =>
    {
                item.Caption = "Kategori";
                item.CaptionSettings.AssociatedNestedExtensionName = "kategoriFaktur";
                item.SetNestedContent(() =>
                {                
                    @Html.RenderPartial("_cbPartialCategories", Model);            
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the `IsPostBack` property on the form load event when popuating the combo box (dropdownlist)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           //Code to populate the Combo Box
        }
    }
```

The Combo box is reset each time the page is post back hence the above code will avoid doing that. It will populate the Combobox only the first time the page is requested.

Comment: is it work in MVC, how about my combobox is partial view or razor view?

Comment: Above will work for web forms not razor in mvc. To do this in MVC Razor, please see this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555241/how-to-save-selected-dropdownlist-value-in-asp-net-mvc-model-for-post

Comment: I still confused with your explanation. sorry.